# Performance impact of base image in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am learning to use docker. I want to dockerize a java application. Is there any difference in performance or resource usage(other than disk space) if I use a minimal base image like busybox instead of ubuntu (debian) as the base image in docker?

Comment: Related: [Phusion/BaseImage](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All else being equal, the base image shouldn't **directly** affect performance / resource usage: there will be a single process running in your container, so your application is the only thing that *can* consume any resources. No matter what else exists on the file system.

That said, I can imagine differences caused **indirectly** by your choice of base image: default JVM options, the version of the JVM that the package manager on your image installs; any difference in the environment really. No more examples come to mind, but I'm sure there can be some down the stack.